# How to execute SP in for each and union all results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, for-loop, union

I have a table with certain records, let's call this the **Priority** table. For each record in this table I need to execute a stored procedure called `GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord` which returns records from a **Product** table. 
All these results need to be returned as one UNION without duplicates.

I'm able to write the following C# pseodo code, but I have no idea on how to do this in SQL:

```
//DECLARE resultVariable
var products = new List<Product>();

//SELECT * FROM Priority and FOREACH over this
foreach(var prio in Priority) {
    //EXEC GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord and UNION this on the resultVariable
    products.Union(GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord(prio));
}

//RETURN resultVariable
return products;
```

Comment: If this is what you want? Please see the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23b58/6. Or otherwise provide sample resulting rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be writing SQL code in loops if you need it to perform even relatively well. But this is what I would do in this case.

```
-- build some variables
declare @prio           table (prio varchar(100) not null)
declare @singlePrio     varchar(50)
declare @sqlcmd         varchar(50)

-- assuming that the output of the stored procedure is just a table of INTs
declare @output         table (outputID int not null)

-- build the list to loop over
insert into @prio (prio)
select * from [Priority]

while exists (select 1 from @prio)
begin
    select @singlePrio = (select top 1 prio from @prio)
    --
    insert into @output exec GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord @singlePrio
    --
    delete from @prio where prio = @singlePrio
end

-- using distinct because you want a 'union' but didnt say 'union all'
select distinct outputID from @output
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be able to do it with a cursor. It's not always the best way. I assume that you are forced to use the existing stored procedure.

Example tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [PriorityID] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Priority](
    [PriorityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PriorityCode] [nchar](10) NULL)
```

(with PKs etc).

Sample stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PriorityID int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE PriorityID = @PriorityID
END
```

Then something like this:

```
DECLARE @PriorityID INT
DECLARE @table TABLE (ProductID INT, ProductName NCHAR(10), PriorityID INT)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT PriorityID FROM Priority
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @PriorityID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table EXEC GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord @PriorityID
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @PriorityID
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @table
```

Of course this makes some assumptions about your tables. Also (of course) a synthetic example like this is actually showing a long-winded way of doing something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (outputID INT NOT NULL) 

SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT CHAR(13) + '
        INSERT INTO #temp(outputID) 
        EXEC dbo.GetProductsBasedOnPriorityRecord ''' 
            + prio + ''''
    FROM dbo.[Priority]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT DISTINCT outputID 
FROM #temp
```